# How to make custom shorcut key as ctrl+Ç(ç is turkish char) for a menu item in c#

Tags: c#, .net, menuitem, shortcut

I want to make keyboard shorcut key in c# but since i could not find any "Ç" char on keyboard shorcuts list for menu items. So I decided to make it as my own keydown event for parent control. But it didn't work. The problem may be it does not see the char 'Ç' there. So i want change it as Keys.Ç like casual english chars. Is there anyway to do that? Here is my code below:

```
private void mniOpenW_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "ç" ) || (e.Control == true && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "Ç"))
        {
            mniOpenW.PerformClick();
        }
    }
```

I want to make it like that:

```
private void mniOpenW_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Ç)
        {
            mniOpenW.PerformClick();
        }
    }
```

Is there any way that i can find that button in c#? Because I could not find it myself. Or something make that code working is also good for me.

Comment: No. `Keys` is an enumeration built by Microsoft. The way you have it in your top example is the only way to get keys not in the enumeration other than using the int version of the `e.KeyCode` that those characters return.

Comment: I tried it with the first code but it did not perform. So what can make it work? Is my first code wrong? What do i miss here?

Comment: Take a look at what `e.KeyCode` gives you. Chances are then, that `e.KeyCode.ToString()` doesn't give you what you're expecting. You'd probably want `KeyValue` instead. [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You have to use virtual keys, they are the same anywhere in the world.  On a Turkish keyboard that letter is produced by the 2nd key to the left of the right shift key.  So you need if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.OemPeriod)) { /* etc */ }

Comment: Thanks Hans i exactly did same thing and it worked :) i looked its keydata and keyvalue by wtiring it on a textbox, then used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar to Hans' comment and it worked for me. Here is my code below:

```
private void mniOpenW_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyValue == 220)//this is keyvalue of 'Ç' key.
        {
            mniOpenW.PerformClick();
        }
    }
```